# Limit Amount of icons on google map depends on zoom distance

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

Currently Using this code

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> markersArray = new ArrayList<MarkerData>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < markersArray.size() ; i++) {

    createMarker(markersArray.get(i).getLatitude(), markersArray.get(i).getLongitude(), markersArray.get(i).getTitle(), markersArray.get(i).getSnippet(), markersArray.get(i).getIconResID());
}


protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {

    return googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
}
```

And i have no issue with it, but my problem is if i have like 50 mark in 1 city, all of the icons are on top of each other.

Is there's way to limit how many icons get displayed if the map is zoomed out? or maybe better practice

Comment: Have you considered marker clustering approach? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/#clustering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to check the zoom when update and hide the markers you want

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

private float currentZoom = mMap.zoom;

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition newPosition) {
    if (newPosition.zoom < currentZoom){
        // remove a particular marker
        yourMarker.remove();
       // or remove all the markers
       googleMap.clear();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I think that the best way is to just hide all markers if zoom level was too low